# I am using List Class in my project and it continuously giving the below mentioned error.

Tags: java, eclipse, list

I am using List Class in my project and it continuously giving the below mentioned error. 
I have tried using new Eclipse and new workspace but then same problem.
Selected java.util.List in auto import.
Moved JRE System Library  to the top in eclipse.

Is there any solution for this problem?

HTTP Status 500 -

---

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 0 in the generated java file
The type Enumeration is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

An error occurred at line: 13 in the generated java file
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

An error occurred at line: 18 in the generated java file
The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 logs.

---

Apache Tomcat/7.0.14

Comment: Could you please show the code of your JSP? It would help us solve your issue.

Comment: It is as simple as this.

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method = "post" action = "FileUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type = "text" name = "txtBox" />
 <input type = "file" name = "upldFile" />
 <input type = "submit" name = "submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Take a look under the work directory-you should have a Java file generated from your jsp, check it out as a starting point

Comment: public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException{
     

     if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
         System.out.println("Inside if");
        }

     DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

        factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);

        factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
        
        ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

        upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);

Comment: upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

          
        String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
                + File.separator + UPLOAD_DIRECTORY;

        File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
        if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
            uploadDir.mkdir();
        }
        
        try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);